# Object is nil after calling a method in Rails test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm experiencing unexpected behavior in running tests with rspec and rails. I have a class method, `create_and_save`, which saves an association to a `recipient` object.

If, at any point in this method, I output the `recipient`, I get what I expect:

```
Rails.logger.debug recipient.to_s
# => #<User:0x007fb712572210>
```

But as soon as I try to access an attribute or method on the `recipient`, I run into an error.

```
Rails.logger.debug recipient.id.to_s
# => undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Rails.logger.debug recipient.valid?.to_s
# => undefined method `valid?' for nil:NilClass
```

If I check for `nil?` the behavior follows a similar pattern. Without another call, I'm fine:

```
Rails.logger.debug recipient.nil?.to_s
# => false
```

But when I try to access a method, `recipient` is retroactively `nil`.

```
Rails.logger.debug recipient.nil?.to_s
# => true
Rails.logger.debug recipient.id.to_s
# => undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

In development, the method works as expected. So I'm guessing this has something to do with how my test environment is running, but I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: can you show larger block of code this picked line not help to identify the problem!

Comment: Good call! Actually, in working to simplify the method so I could explain what was happening, I identified the problem. Funny how that works.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your database is up-to-date in you test environment.

The easiest way is to recreate the test DB with:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

Comment: This didn't solve my particular problem, but it's good advice. I've run into this before. Note that as of Rails 4.1 `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!` in the `rails_helper` works to keep test environment in sync with development.

Answer (score 0):

In working to add more context to my problem, I found the culprit. The method was being called twice. The first time the `recipient` was indeed `nil`, while when it ran the second time, it had a recipient.

Validations and better checks for `nil` objects would have likely caught this sooner.

I will also note that the reason I believed `Rails.logger.debug recipient.nil?.to_s` was returning `false` when I didn't attempt to access an attribute was because that's what I saw at the end of the transaction. Because the initial call occurred in the middle of several transactions, it got lost in the mess. Using `puts` to print to the window running rspec made this easier to debug.